# Building audio processing Little Endian SDK with NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, audio-processing

I am trying to use `ndk-build` to use native code for audio processing from [Little Endian](http://www.littleendian.com/developers/) in an Android application (I don't have JNI yet).

When I executed ndk-build in jni dir I got ($USER_PATH is path to directory on my computer):

```
Android NDK: WARNING: Rebuilding libc++ libraries from sources!    
Android NDK: You might want to use $NDK/build/tools/build-cxx-stl.sh --stl=libc++    
Android NDK: in order to build prebuilt versions to speed up your builds!    
Android NDK: ERROR:$USER_PATH/android-ndk-r10/sources/android/compiler-rt/Android.mk:compiler_rt_shared: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
Android NDK: $USER_PATH/Android/android-ndk-r10/sources/android/compiler-rt/libs/armeabi/libcompiler_rt_shared.so exists  or that its path is correct   
$USER_PATH/android-ndk-r10/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

I saw that is because of PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY which points to missing files.

How can I solve this?

Directory structure:
[image]

There are .mk files:

### Android.mk

```
MY_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

ifndef LE_SDK_PATH
    LE_SDK_PATH := $(call my-dir)
endif

include $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/le_audioio.mk
include $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/le_utility.mk

LOCAL_PATH := ${MY_LOCAL_PATH}
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE           := little-endian
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := le_audioio le_utility

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

### Application.mk

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
APP_STL      := c++_static
APP_ABI      := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
APP_OPTIM    := release
APP_CFLAGS   += -g

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```

### le_audioio.mk

```
ifndef LE_SDK_PATH
    LE_SDK_PATH := $(call my-dir)
endif

LOCAL_PATH:= $(LE_SDK_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE            := le_audioio
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(abspath $(LE_SDK_PATH)/include)
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS     += -lOpenSLES
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := libs/development/libAudioIO_Android_x86-32_SSSE3.a
else
    ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
        LOCAL_ARM_NEON  := true
        LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/development/libAudioIO_Android_ARMv7a_NEON.a
    else
        LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/release/libAudioIO_Android_ARMv6_VFP2.a
    endif
endif

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

### le_utilityio.mk

```
ifndef LE_SDK_PATH
    LE_SDK_PATH := $(call my-dir)
endif

LOCAL_PATH:= $(LE_SDK_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE            := le_utility
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(abspath $(LE_SDK_PATH)/include)
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS     += -landroid -llog
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := libs/development/libUtility_Android_x86-32_SSSE3.a
else
    ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
        LOCAL_ARM_NEON  := true
        LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/development/libUtility_Android_ARMv7a_NEON.a
    else
        LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := libs/release/libUtility_Android_ARMv6_VFP2.a
        LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS += -latomic
    endif
endif

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: I checked that removing NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang and APP_STL      := c++_static from Application.mk builds with success.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing the logic needed for shared and static libraries. What do you actually want to use in your application? The current logic specifies BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY but requests a static version of the C++ stl.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://github.com/google/oboe/tree/master/samples) a new solution by Google for audio application.